# zsh set as default shell for root

Tags: linux, zsh

Can I set zsh as default shell while being logged in as root? I did `chsh -s /bin/zsh` and used my root password for authentication, but failed.

Comment: You want to set your user or root shell to zsh?

Comment: I want to set root shell to zsh

Comment: Don't use your user password at the prompt; use root's password.

Comment: Already did login using root's password.

Comment: It is unclear whether the command failed due to authentication issues, or because `/bin/zsh` is not a valid shell on your system.

Answer (score 6):

A trick is to set interactive root shells to use zsh and leave non-interactive shells to continue to use /bin/sh.

This can still lead to "expectation" problems as described in other responses but at least you will not blow up any non-interactive processes.

Add the following to the end of /root/.bashrc

```
if [ ! -z "$PS1" ]; then
    exec /bin/zsh $*
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

In general it is a bad idea to change the root shell away from /bin/sh. It is better to add another account, e.g. zroot, that still has a UID of 0 but has zsh as a shell. However to attempt to answer the question, if you are logging in as root, then you don't need to use `sudo`. Just use

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh root
```

and give the `root` password in response to the request from chsh. Worth specifing the 'root' explicitly.

If you are logging in as 'fred', then use

```
sudo -i
```

and answer the password request with `fred's` password. This should give you a root shell. Proceed as if you had originally logged in as root.

Make sure the /bin/zsh is listed in /etc/shells.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to change root’s login shell to something other than `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @k.stm The system is set up knowing the shell for root, so instructions are written based on that knowledge. /bin/sh might be  staticly linked to avoid library dependencies. The new shell might require some files which are not available in the early boot stages. Given the cost of another couple of hundred bytes of disk space to create an additional account, it seems worthwhile to avoid all the unknown problems.

Comment: Changing the root's login shell to something else implies the root user will be used for interactive work.  This is not generally a good idea. Instead, use `sudo` (or similar tool) for the very few specific administrative tasks that you need to perform.  This is the main reason I would not suggest changing the root user's shell (or doing any kind of changes to the default setup of the root user's environment).  Also, use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to execute it has root. Execute the following command:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Comment: sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh asks for password which I enter correctly but still authentication failure.

Comment: If you don't know your own password I can't help. If you know the root password try execute just `su` before this command.

Comment: I am already logged in to root, as my question explained.

Comment: type "whoami" to see if you're really root ...

Comment: Also check the path of the shell you're trying to switch to. It's unclear whether it is the authentication or something else that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit /etc/passwd using a text editor. There is one line for user root containing the current shell which you can change to zsh.

Don't log out to test the new settings but use a second terminal! Because in case you make a mistake you may not be able to login again to repair it.

Comment: Never edit the password database with a text editor without using `vipw`.  Also note that the question does not make it clear that it is the _authentication_ that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Editing passwd file with normal editor is not recommended
to do this use

```
vipw
```

and change shell to zsh,honestly i don't understand why you want to change
the root shell,root account must used only for administration thing,for normal work use unprivileged user.
After this try to log in on other tty whitout(is important) disconnect from current tty,if works you can see your new shell.
If you want to use immediately zsh,simply type zsh.
Conclusion

```
I want to use my new shell now = type zsh
I want to use my new shell + change = chsh -s or vipw
```

p.s= if your zsh is not installed on those path(/bin /sbin..)
and you have to do a single user login with root,will not work
because cannot find your shell,this can happen also on system with /usr
separated from root/mounted on other lvm or partition

Answer (score 0):

how about setting your `default` **root** `shell` using `usermod` utility:

```bsh
sudo usermod --shell /bin/zsh root
```

works like a charm for me and its very simple.

you have `proof` in `/etc/passwd` line `1`.

this is `permanently` and you dont have add any garbage to your .bashrc file.