# Where can I find the source code of Voidlinux

Tags: linux, kernel, void-linux, open-source, runit

## Why do I need to know where is the code source?

I found a ***bug*** in the **config** file of the service named `wpa_supplicant`, when using some shell, like `sh` or `zsh`  instead of `bash` for the `root` user

```bsh
$ cat /etc/passwd

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/zsh
```

this error is in this file : `/etc/sv/wpa_supplicant/auto`

- Because in bash, we can find in two directories like that

```bsh
for f in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-*.conf /etc/wpa_supplicant-*.conf ; 
do 
   #....
done
```

but we can't do it in another shell

- my `PR` is changing this `for-loop` or adding `bash shebang`,

***but can't find `Void-Linux source in GitHub***

Comment: why do you require the source code? ... are you asking for the kernel source code?

Comment: Have you considered either (1) filing a bug report with the owners of the distribution or (2) asking the owners for a copy of the source code under GPL version 2?

Comment: this file `/etc/sv/wpa_supplicant/auto` needed for wifi (`wpa_supplicant`) ,it's work only with bash.  i want to tell the contrubors of voidlinux to change to work with zsh and sh to

Comment: Also, see this answer on why changing root's default shell is a bad idea: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318437/90691

Comment: @doneal2 I can't find the source code , the question is, where is it?

Comment: Your inability to find the source code is why one of my suggestions was to ask the distributors for it.

Comment: that's not a bug in voidlinux or its wpa_supplicant package.  that's you breaking your own system by setting root's shell to zsh.   Things can (and often do) break if you change root's shell, as the entire system is set up to expect that root has that shell.  If you want to run zsh as root, just run `exec zsh` as soon as you login as root, or run `sudo -i zsh` to get a root zsh shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/void-linux).

Your eventual pull request would modify [this file](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/blob/master/srcpkgs/wpa_supplicant/files/wpa_supplicant/auto).

You could first file a bug report (an issue in Github). That lets other people see the problem and search for solutions. Then you could create the PR and associate it with the issue.

The document [Contributing to void-packages](https://github.com/void-linux/void-packages/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) has more information on how to contribute.