# Why not run zsh-newuser-install as root?

Tags: zsh, configuration

My user shell is `zsh`, but sometimes I need to wander about as root, where my shell customizations (prompts, aliases, etc.) don't come with me. So I thought if I'm going to be adding those all, I might as well change the entire shell to `zsh`.

Surprisingly, however, after I did change my shell to `zsh`, it didn't generate me a `.zshrc` as it did for my user. Looking about online I learned about the `zsh-newuser-install -f` function, which then spits out an error:

```
hostname: # zsh-newuser-install -f
zsh-newuser-install: won't run as root.  Read the manual.
```

So I did, but it didn't tell me anything new.

From [the manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#User-Configuration-Functions):

> As currently configured, the function will exit immediately if the user has root privileges; this behaviour cannot be overridden.

It doesn't tell me *why*, though. And after going down this rabbit hole of "how hard can it be to get `zsh` to generate a `.zshrc` for root" I'm more curious than ever.

I can copy over my user `.zshrc`, but why will it not generate one for me?

Comment: The "Read the manual" means "Read the manual to learn how to configure the shell". It does not mean "Read the manual to see why you can't run this function as root".

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't think of that interpretation :) Regardless, I also thought the manual would have more information, including about why I can't run it as root.

Comment: Probably they don't want to be blamed for locking someone out of the root account. Run it as a normal user and copy the generated `.zshrc` to `/root` once you've got things as you like them.

Answer (score -1):

as others have pointed out *[it's a bad idea to change the root shell away from /bin/sh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318437/271043)*  It is better to add another account, e.g. toor, that still has a UID of 0 but has zsh as a shell. the benefit of this is that root has it's shell untouched so it can't potentially be broken and not be able to login by a bad update from a different shell, another option is when you need to work as root for more than a handful of commands, simply do

`sudo -Es`[2](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sudo.8#E) [3](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sudo.8#s)

this will start zsh as root with your regular rc files and $HOME will point to your regular home directory.

now if you use a zsh framework such as oh my zsh, you may get warnings such as insecure completion-dependent directories you can safely disable those.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but I'm looking for the reason why `zsh-newuser-install -f` won't generate a `.zshrc` for root, regardless of whether changing the default shell for root is a good idea or not.